# How can I get all the same JSON key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{"Object":[
    { "date" : "Fri Jan 20 08:00:00",
        "events" : {
            "birthday" : { "num": 0 },
            "meeting" : { "num" : 2 },
            "reminder" : { "num" : 1}  
        }
    } ,
    { "date" : "Fri Jan 21 08:00:00",
        "events" : {
            "birthday" : { "num": 1 },
            "meeting" : { "num" : 0 },
            "reminder" : { "num" : 2}  
        }
    }]
}
```

Currently I use `map()` and a `for()` loop inside my map to format my results (this is not the exact code, I don't have it on this computer):

```
results.map(function(objDate){
    arrDate.push(objDate.date);
    for(var value in objDate.events){
        arrValue[item].push(objDate.events[value])
    }    
});
```

(I need array to display charts)
This give me 2 array:

```
arrDate: ["Fri Jan 20 08:00:00", "Fri Jan 21 08:00:00"]
arrValues: [[0,1],[2,0],[1,2]]
```

This works great but when my JSON file gives me too much results (like 600,000) it takes time (not a lot, but still too much) to format it.

I can't change the JSON file because it comes from another application.

Is there any possibilities to get all "birthday" key directly without iterating into all date? Or maybe still iterate each date but optimizing my loops?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To use `map` as it's intended, the callback should `return` a value. Otherwise, you should use `forEach`.

Comment: try using for loop instead of map

Comment: What's `item` in your code? Why are you using `map` when you're not returning anything from the `map` callback or using the result? Are the keys always going to be the same (`birthday`, `meeting`, `reminder`)? Or at least the same for all events in the same file?

Comment: Native `for` loop is (ans probably will always be) faster than `.map`, because in `.map`, You have function call overhead every iteration. See for example this benchmark: http://jsben.ch/#/BQhED

Comment: I use map because it was the best solution before, and I didn't change it when I change my algorithm.

Yes it's always the same format

Comment: ...and (again) what's `item` in your code?

Comment: It's just an incrementation (from 0 to 2 in this case) to access to the array in arrValues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `map` incorrectly, and don't need to use it at all, so that's one improvement you can make. A simple `for` loop should suffice.

You've said the keys in the event objects don't change, so you can avoid the `for-in` loop, which is expensive.

You haven't told us what `item` in your code is, so it's hard to be specific, but something *like* this:

```
var index, length, objDate, entry, events;
for (index = 0, length = results.length; index < length; ++index) {
    objDate = results[index];
    arrDate.push(objDate.date);
    entry = arrValue[item];
    events = objDate.events;
    entry.push(events.birthday);
    entry.push(events.meeting);
    entry.push(events.reminder);
}
```